# MySQl Error #1064

Tags: mysql, mysql-error-1064

I keep getting this error:

> MySQL said: #1064 - You have an error
>   in your SQL syntax; check the manual
>   that corresponds to your MySQL server
>   version for the right syntax to use
>   near 'INSERT INTO
>   books.book(isbn10,isbn13,title,edition,author_f_name,author_m_na'
>   at line 15

with this query:

```
USE books;

DROP TABLE IF EXISTS book;


    CREATE TABLE `books`.`book`(
    `book_id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT PRIMARY KEY,
    `isbn10` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `isbn13` VARCHAR(15) NOT NULL,
    `title` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `edition` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `author_f_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `author_m_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `author_l_name` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `cond` ENUM('as new','very good','good','fair','poor') NOT NULL,
    `price` DECIMAL(8,2) NOT NULL,
    `genre` VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
    `quantity` INT NOT NULL)

    INSERT INTO books.book(isbn10,isbn13,title,edition,author_f_name,author_m_name,author_l_name,cond,price,genre,quantity)** 
    VALUES ('0136061699','978-0136061694','Software Engineering: Theory and Practice','4','Shari','Lawrence','Pfleeger','very good','50','Computing','2');
```

Any idea what the problem is?

Comment: Don't ya love the super-helpful mySQL error messages?  It takes this old-timer back to the days of "IEH407I Probable Programmer Error", which was OS/360 talk for "eh?"

Comment: @Ollie, these errors are like the thorns on a rose.

Comment: By the way, in general, watch also for reserved words in your table or column names. This was the problem that brought me here for the same message (because it wasn't an 'obvious' reserved word).

Answer (score 26, accepted):

maybe you forgot to add "`;`" after this line of code:

```
`quantity` INT NOT NULL)
```

Answer (score 3):

In my case I was having the same error and later I come to know that the '**condition**' is mysql reserved keyword and I used that as field name.

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes when your table has a similar name to the database name you should use back tick. so instead of:

```
INSERT INTO books.book(field1, field2) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
```

You should have this:

```
INSERT INTO `books`.`book`(`field1`, `field2`) VALUES ('value1', 'value2');
```

Answer (score 0):

At first you need to add semi colon (;) after `quantity INT NOT NULL)`
then remove ** from `,genre,quantity)**`.
to insert a value with numeric data type like int, decimal, float, etc you don't need to add single quote.