# #1064 Error : While "If Then Insert"

Tags: mysql

```
SELECT id INTO @aid 
FROM `lista` 
WHERE aname='teszt' LIMIT 0,1;

IF ISNULL(@aid) 
THEN INSERT INTO `szer_k` (`id`,`a`,`b`) VALUES (NULL, 'Teszt2',10);
```

It says:

```
#1064 error
```

(problem is null?)

I would love it if the `@aid` is `NULL` then perform the insert command.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706498/mysql-error-1064

Comment: Typo? "@aid,);" has a comma too many?

Comment: Now see my modified answer

Answer (score 4):

Since you are checking that `ISNULL(@aid)`.
If it is a NULL then only `Insert` statement will get fired. In `values` clause `@aid` is present. Which is `NULL` and checked already. Hence replace `@aid` with `NULL`.

```
SELECT id INTO @aid 
  FROM lista 
 WHERE aname='teszt' LIMIT 0,1; 

IF ISNULL(@aid) THEN 
  INSERT INTO szer_k (id,a,b) 
  VALUES (NULL, 'Teszt2',NULL);
END IF
```

**UPDATE :**

You were missing `END IF` at the end.
**[See here Syntax](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/if.html)**

Comment: YOu should explain what you changed in the query, so he'll understand what he did wrong.

Comment: `VALUES (NULL, 'Teszt2',@aid);` to `VALUES (NULL, 'Teszt2',NULL);`