# > Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL > syntax;

Tags: php, mysql, registration

I am using the following signup/login php script with mysql:

https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced>

The thing is that when I modify the Registration class found here: https://github.com/panique/php-login-advanced/blob/master/classes/Registration.php

in order to add my extra fields I have crated in my table in the database the registration does not work. The error I get is:

---

> Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL
>   syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version
>   for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 )

---

My table is this one:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
`user_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT COMMENT 'auto incrementing user_id of each        user, unique index', 
`user_name` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s name, unique',
`user_password_hash` varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s password in salted and hashed format',
`user_email` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email, unique',
`user_active` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user''s activation status',
`user_activation_hash` varchar(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'user''s email verification hash string',
`user_password_reset_hash` char(40) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'user''s password reset code',
`user_password_reset_timestamp` bigint(20) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'timestamp of the password reset request',
`user_rememberme_token` varchar(64) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL COMMENT  'user''s remember-me cookie token',
`user_failed_logins` tinyint(1) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'user''s failed login attemps',
`user_last_failed_login` int(10) DEFAULT NULL COMMENT 'unix timestamp of last failed login attempt',
`user_registration_datetime` datetime NOT NULL DEFAULT '0000-00-00 00:00:00',
`user_registration_ip` varchar(39) COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.0.0.0',
`firstname` char(50) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`lastname` char(100) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`gender` enum('Woman','Man') COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci DEFAULT NULL,
`dob` date NOT NULL COMMENT 'date of birth',
`city` char(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL,
`address` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`zipcode` varchar(10) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`county` varchar(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`phone_number` int(14) NOT NULL,
`nationality` varchar(255) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`occupation` char(25) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`income` varchar(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`marital_status` char(15) CHARACTER SET utf8 DEFAULT NULL,
`account_permissions` enum('user','admin') CHARACTER SET utf8 NOT NULL DEFAULT 'user',
PRIMARY KEY (`user_id`),
UNIQUE KEY `user_name` (`user_name`),
UNIQUE KEY `user_email` (`user_email`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM AUTO_INCREMENT=7 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci   COMMENT='user data';
```

`
I modify the Registration class as following:

```
public function __construct()
{
    session_start();    
    // if we have such a POST request, call the registerNewUser() method
    if (isset($_POST["register"])) {
        $this->registerNewUser($_POST['user_name'],
                                $_POST['firstname'],
                                $_POST['lastname'],
                                $_POST['sexradio'],
                                $_POST['dob'],
                                $_POST['city'],
                                $_POST['address'],
                                $_POST['zipcode'],
                                $_POST['county'],
                                $_POST['phone'],
                                $_POST['user_email'],
                                $_POST['nationality'],
                                $_POST['position'],
                                $_POST['income'],
                                $_POST['maritalstatusradio'],
                                $_POST['user_password_new'], 
                                $_POST['user_password_repeat'], 
                                $_POST["captcha"]);
    // if we have such a GET request, call the verifyNewUser() method
    }
```

and inside the registerNewUser function I am adding:

```
$query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime, firstname, lastname, gender, dob, city, address, zipcode, county, phone_number, nationality, occupation, income, marital_status) 
VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now(), :firstname, :lastname, :sexradio, :dob, :city, :address, :zipcode, :county, :phone, :nationality, :position, :income, :maritalstatusradio');
```

and

```
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_activation_hash', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_registration_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':sexradio', $sexradio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':dob', $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':zipcode', $zipcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':county', $county, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':nationality', $nationality, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':position', $position, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':income', $income, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':maritalstatusradio', $maritalstatusradio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
$query_new_user_insert->execute();
```

the html form is:

```
<form method="post" action="register.php" name="registerform" id="regForm">
  <fieldset>
   <label for="user_name">Kasutajanimi*</label>
   <input id="user_name" type="text" pattern="[a-zA-Z0-9]{2,64}" name="user_name" required />
  <?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_USERNAME; ?>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <label>Eesnimi*</label>
   <input name="firstname" type="text">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <label>Perkonnanimi*</label>
   <input name="lastname" type="text">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset class="radio-group">
   <h3>Sugu</h3>
   <div class="radio-options">
   <p>
    <input name="sexradio" type="radio" id="sex-man"> 
    <label for="sex-man">Mees</label>
   </p>
   <p>
     <input name="sexradio" type="radio" id="sex-woman"> 
     <label for="sex-woman">Naine</label>
   </p>
   </div>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <label>Sünniaeg*</label>
   <input name="dob" type="text">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Linn/asula*</label>
    <input name="city" type="text">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Aadress</label>
    <input name="address" type="text">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
    <label>Postikood</label>
    <input name="zipcode" type="text">
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
   <label>Maakond</label>
   <select name="county" id="select-county">
       <option>Harju maakond</option>
       <option>Hiiu maakond</option>
       <option>Ida-Viru maakond</option>
   </select>
  </fieldset>
  <fieldset>
     <label>Sissetulek</label>
     <select name="income" id="select-income">
        <option>kuni 500</option>
        <option>500-1000</option>
        ...
     </select>
   </fieldset>
   <fieldset class="radio-group">
     <h3>Perekonnaseis</h3>
     <div class="radio-options">
     <p>
      <input name="maritalstatusradio" type="radio" id="marital-status-single"> 
      <label for="marital-status-single">Vallaline</label>
     </p>
     <p><input name="maritalstatusradio" type="radio" id="marital-status-married"> <label for="marital-status-married">Abielus</label></p>
     <p><input name="maritalstatusradio" type="radio" id="marital-status-cohabitation"> <label for="marital-status-cohabitation">Vabaabielu</label></p>
     <p><input name="maritalstatusradio" type="radio" id="marital-status-widow"> <label for="marital-status-widow">Lesk</label></p>
     </div>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <label for="user_password_new">Password</label>
     <input id="user_password_new" type="password" name="user_password_new" pattern=".{6,}" required autocomplete="off" />
     <?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_PASSWORD; ?>
    </fieldset>
    <fieldset>
     <label for="user_password_repeat">Repeat password</label>
     <input id="user_password_repeat" type="password" name="user_password_repeat" pattern=".{6,}" required autocomplete="off" />
     <?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_PASSWORD_REPEAT; ?>
     </fieldset>
     <img src="tools/showCaptcha.php" alt="captcha" />
     <fieldset>
     <label><?php echo WORDING_REGISTRATION_CAPTCHA; ?></label>
     <input type="text" name="captcha" required />
     </fieldset>
     <fieldset>
      <input type="submit" name="register" value="Registreeru" class="btn"/>
     </fieldset>

    </form>
```

and the registerNewUser method

```
    private function registerNewUser($user_name, $firstname, $lastname, 
    $sexradio, $dob, $city, $address, $zipcode, $county, $phone, $user_email, 
    $nationality, $position, $income, $maritalstatusradio, $user_password,  $user_password_repeat, $captcha)

    {
    // we just remove extra space on username and email
    $user_name  = trim($user_name);
    $user_email = trim($user_email);

    // check provided data validity
    // TODO: check for "return true" case early, so put this first
    if (strtolower($captcha) != strtolower($_SESSION['captcha'])) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_CAPTCHA_WRONG;
    } elseif (empty($user_name)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_EMPTY;

    } elseif (empty($firstname)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_FIRSTNAME_EMPTY;
    } elseif (empty($lastname)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_LASTNAME_EMPTY;
    } elseif (empty($dob)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_DOB_EMPTY;
    } elseif (empty($city)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_CITY_EMPTY;
    } elseif (empty($phone)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PHONE_EMPTY;


    } elseif (empty($user_password) || empty($user_password_repeat)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_EMPTY;
    } elseif ($user_password !== $user_password_repeat) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_BAD_CONFIRM;
    } elseif (strlen($user_password) < 6) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_PASSWORD_TOO_SHORT;
    } elseif (strlen($user_name) > 64 || strlen($user_name) < 2) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_BAD_LENGTH;
    } elseif (!preg_match('/^[a-z\d]{2,64}$/i', $user_name)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_USERNAME_INVALID;
    } elseif (empty($user_email)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_EMAIL_EMPTY;
    } elseif (strlen($user_email) > 64) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_EMAIL_TOO_LONG;
    } elseif (!filter_var($user_email, FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)) {
        $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_EMAIL_INVALID;

    // finally if all the above checks are ok
    } else if ($this->databaseConnection()) {
        // check if username or email already exists
        $query_check_user_name = $this->db_connection->prepare('SELECT user_name, user_email FROM users WHERE user_name=:user_name OR user_email=:user_email');
        $query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_check_user_name->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query_check_user_name->execute();
        $result = $query_check_user_name->fetchAll();

        // if username or/and email find in the database
        // TODO: this is really awful!
        if (count($result) > 0) {
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($result); $i++) {
                $this->errors[] = ($result[$i]['user_name'] == $user_name) ? MESSAGE_USERNAME_EXISTS : MESSAGE_EMAIL_ALREADY_EXISTS;
            }
        } else {
            // check if we have a constant HASH_COST_FACTOR defined (in config/hashing.php),
            // if so: put the value into $hash_cost_factor, if not, make $hash_cost_factor = null
            $hash_cost_factor = (defined('HASH_COST_FACTOR') ? HASH_COST_FACTOR : null);

            // crypt the user's password with the PHP 5.5's password_hash() function, results in a 60 character hash string
            // the PASSWORD_DEFAULT constant is defined by the PHP 5.5, or if you are using PHP 5.3/5.4, by the password hashing
            // compatibility library. the third parameter looks a little bit shitty, but that's how those PHP 5.5 functions
            // want the parameter: as an array with, currently only used with 'cost' => XX.
            $user_password_hash = password_hash($user_password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT, array('cost' => $hash_cost_factor));
            // generate random hash for email verification (40 char string)
            $user_activation_hash = sha1(uniqid(mt_rand(), true));

            // write new users data into database
            $query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name, 
                user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime, 
                firstname, lastname, gender, dob, city, address, zipcode, county, phone_number, nationality, 
                occupation, income, marital_status) 
            VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now(), 
                :firstname, :lastname, :sexradio, :dob, :city, :address, :zipcode, :county, :phone, :nationality, 
                :position, :income, :maritalstatusradio');


            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_name', $user_name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_password_hash', $user_password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_email', $user_email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_activation_hash', $user_activation_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':user_registration_ip', $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'], PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':firstname', $firstname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':lastname', $lastname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':sexradio', $sexradio, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':dob', $dob, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':city', $city, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':zipcode', $zipcode, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':county', $county, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':phone', $phone, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':nationality', $nationality, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':position', $position, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':income', $income, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query_new_user_insert->bindValue(':maritalstatusradio', $maritalstatusradio, PDO::PARAM_STR);

            $query_new_user_insert->execute();

            $errorMessage=$query_new_user_insert->errorInfo(); 
            print_r($errorMessage);
            // id of new user
            $user_id = $this->db_connection->lastInsertId();

            if ($query_new_user_insert) {
                // send a verification email
                if ($this->sendVerificationEmail($user_id, $user_email, $user_activation_hash)) {
                    // when mail has been send successfully
                    $this->messages[] = MESSAGE_VERIFICATION_MAIL_SENT;
                    $this->registration_successful = true;
                } else {
                    // delete this users account immediately, as we could not send a verification email
                    $query_delete_user = $this->db_connection->prepare('DELETE FROM users WHERE user_id=:user_id');
                    $query_delete_user->bindValue(':user_id', $user_id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                    $query_delete_user->execute();

                    $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_VERIFICATION_MAIL_ERROR;
                }
            } else {
                $this->errors[] = MESSAGE_REGISTRATION_FAILED;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is somewhere in the insert statement and probably has to do with the quotation marks.

Any help appreciated.! :)

Comment: Does the function accept the new parameters correctly?

Comment: To get the error message: `$errorMessage=$query_new_user_insert->errorInfo(); print_r($errorMessage);`

Comment: @AndreasStorvikStrauman Thank you for your reply. Where do I have to place these lines to see the error?

Comment: (It looks like you use PHPs `PDO`, so assuming that you do,) running `$errorMessage=$query_new_user_insert->errorInfo();` will make $errorMessage contain an array with the error info. So `print_r($errorMessage)` will just dump it as output too the browser where ever you put it and the browser runs. I.E. If your browser runs the file that calls the registration, you could just put it temporarily below `$query_new_user_insert->execute();`, and it should be visible in the browser :)

Comment: Notice: Undefined variable: sexradio in C:\xampp\htdocs\vemzy\vemzy\register\classes\Registration.php on line 192

Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 )

Comment: Yes I have edit my main post with the method to have a look. :)

Comment: The errors are the following: Array ( [0] => 42000 [1] => 1064 [2] => You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '' at line 7 ) 
Warning: Missing argument 11 for Registration::registerNewUser(), called in C:\xampp\htdocs\vemzy\vemzy\register\classes\Registration.php on line 64 and defined in C:\xampp\htdocs\vemzy\vemzy\register\classes\Registration.php on line 104

Warning: Missing argument 12 for Registration::registerNewUser(), called in IT HAS more errors but I cannot post them all

Comment: Have a look here: http://www.inmotionhosting.com/support/website/database-troubleshooting/error-1064 Accordind to that article, two possible reasons are: **Using reserved words** and **Inserting incompatible data types into a field**. Also, there's some more info here as well: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2706498/mysql-error-1064

Comment: @FelipeAlmeida In my case probably its the second one. But again I am trying to solve this.. Thanks for your respond.

Comment: What, you couldn't narrow it down? Jesus.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally the error was because of a parenthesis that I hadn't closed on the prepare function which holds the sql statement:

```
$query_new_user_insert = $this->db_connection->prepare('INSERT INTO users (user_name,   user_password_hash, user_email, user_activation_hash, user_registration_ip, user_registration_datetime, firstname, lastname, gender, dob, city, address, zipcode, county, phone_number, nationality, occupation, income, marital_status) 
VALUES(:user_name, :user_password_hash, :user_email, :user_activation_hash, :user_registration_ip, now(), :firstname, :lastname, :sexradio, :dob, :city, :address, :zipcode, :county, :phone, :nationality, :position, :income, :maritalstatusradio') );
```